# What Shape Does Naive Bayes make?

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes-classifier

Decision Trees draw straight lines to partition the feature space.
According to the Universal Approximation Theorem, Neural Networks can draw any continuous function.
What sort of shape does the Naive Bayes classifier draw?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifically talking about [Gaussian Naive Bayes](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4780/2018fa/lectures/lecturenote05.html), the decision boundary are ellipsoids characterized by the mean and standard deviation of the Gaussian distribution.

[image]

Image: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-classification-plot-classifier-comparison-py